# Can the interstellar wind / radiation make water undrinkable

Tags: radiation

I was watching a video on the dangers of stellar travel especially interstellar.  The video was discussing the interstellar wind and the damage it could do to the crew.  An option was to place the crews water tanks around the crew cabin to absorb interstellar radiation.

My question is this: Could absorbing all of this radiation make the water either radioactive or not fit for consumption?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: most probably no.

The radiation for humans is dangerous, because it messes up the cellular functions/processes when it hits one. Even if it makes some "unhealty" molecules/atoms in the water, the density of these are really low. So consuming them with the water would have (almost) zero effects for humans.